When I try to view info from my controller, it returns something else
I have another question regarding ASP.NET MVC when you want to display information from a controller in a view but it's not a table, how could you do it? I've tried with ViewData() and ViewBag, but they return this:

System.Collections.Generic.List1[app.IntranetSecurity]

when they should return a query. The purpose of this is to customize the user profile, so that when I start, it tells me whose session it is and displays the name and profile picture on the home screen. From my login controller, I take the Username and send it to my session view controller (dashboard) when it's already started.
In that controller, it's supposed to take the username and query the database, filtering the name to display. I did this
using Session("UserN") = UserNin

my login controller and
Dim UserN As String = Session("UserN")

in my other controller.
Here's the function and how I call it in my HTML to see if you can spot what I'm doing wrong. I'm almost certain it's how I'm exporting it, but I'd like to know your opinion:
Function Index() As ActionResult
            Dim MyConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PAMIntranet_DevConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Dim cnn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
            Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("", cnn)

            'MODELO
            Dim ReportList As List(Of IntranetSecurity) = New List(Of IntranetSecurity)()
            cnn.Open()
            Dim UserN As String = Session("UserN")

            'query de consulta
            Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM IntranetSecurity" &
                                " WHERE (IDEmployee= '" & UserN & "') "
            cmd.CommandText = qry

                Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read()
                    Dim ConsultaNearMissModel As New IntranetSecurity()
                    ConsultaNearMissModel.EmployeeName = reader.GetString(1)

                    ReportList.Add(ConsultaNearMissModel)
                    End While
                End Using

            ViewData("Nombres") = ReportList
            cnn.Close()
            Return View()
        End Function

And this is how I'm calling it in my view:
<h2>@ViewData("Nombres")</h2>

I've already tried changing how I call the ViewData, but it doesn't work. I changed it to ViewBag, but it didn't work.

What you're seeing is the default string representation of ReportList.  It's a list of objects, not a single raw value.  You'd need to tell the view how to display that data, such as looping over it and outputting specific properties in specific HTML.

okay that sounds logic but how can I do that??? do you have a link to use as example to make my Oun?

I'm not sure about the VB syntax in the view, but this looks like a good reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-vb#looping-code  Your ViewData("Nombres") value is a collection and you want to loop over that collection to output properties from the objects therein.

thank you david that helps me a lot I made it

Great to hear!  I didn't post an answer below since I'm not familiar enough with the specific syntax, but you are encouraged to post an answer demonstrating the solution to help others.

yeah sure!  @For Each item In ViewData("Nombres")                  @<h2>@item.EmployeeName</h2>             Next    ViewData("Nombres") is all the collection and inside that collection you have the type of data that you need saying this  ViewData("Nombres") have inside EmployeeName so you need to call EmployeeName that is inside the collection of ViewData("Nombres")
